# How to make table have same width as container?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My table refuses to stretch to the width of its container despite me using stuff like width 100% in my css.  How can I get it to stretch?

JSFindle:
https://jsfiddle.net/whywymam/fa18e3hn/

HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="row" id="IndivTable">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="inner">
                        <tr class= "spacing">
                            <td class= "spacing"><span class="names">S No.</span></td>
                            <td class= "spacing"><span class="names">Email</span></td>      
                            <td class= "spacing"><span class="names">No. of applicants</span></td>
                            <td class= "spacing"><span class="names">Action</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you try reducing your JSfiddle code to just the **relevant** sections

Comment: You know that you've put a set `width` on the table of 391px?

Comment: putting width:100% on the table is working. https://jsfiddle.net/fa18e3hn/2/. Did it only for the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout.

In your HTML, you have used 8 columns which leaves 4 columns unused.

Add this class -

```
table.inner {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will make your table width `100%` of your 8 columns.
If you want full-width table, then change `col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8` to `col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12`

EDIT:

Add `table` class to your `<table>` tag. Bootstrap has beautiful classes which will automatically make your tables responsive.

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5hpxkeak/)

Comment: Hi I've tried your code but it still does not fit the container. (I've uploaded a picture of the problem) Can you please advise me on any other fix?

Comment: This is because you have used `col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8`. Change it to `col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12`